# Sending Email within loop in a function

Tags: vb.net, email

code is building the email but it is only displaying one row when there is six. I got it correct on the text file but I need it to do the same in the email message. I think I got the for next statement in the wrong location. Here is the example of the code that I am having problem with. I do not know how to place the for next statement without interrupting the `vbLine`

```
        For Each p In query
            If p.Contract_No IsNot Nothing Then
                ContractNo = p.Contract_No
            Else
                ContractNo = " "
            End If
            If p.Vendor_Name IsNot Nothing Then
                VenderName = p.Vendor_Name
            Else
                VenderName = " "
            End If
            If p.Termination_Date IsNot Nothing Then
                TerminationDate = p.Termination_Date
                '   ReportDateStr = ReportDate.ToString
                TerminationDateStr = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", TerminationDate)
            Else
                TerminationDateStr = " "
            End If
            If p.Dept_Name IsNot Nothing Then
                DeptName = p.Dept_Name
            Else
                DeptName = " "
            End If
            If p.Renewal_Option_Desc IsNot Nothing Then
                RenewalOption = p.Renewal_Option_Desc
            Else
                RenewalOption = " "
            End If
            If p.Contract_Desc IsNot Nothing Then
                ContractDesc = p.Contract_Desc
            Else
                ContractDesc = " "
            End If
            If p.Contact_Email IsNot Nothing Then
                ContactEmail = p.Contact_Email
            Else
                ContactEmail = "** N/A ** "
            End If



            ' sends email with attachment
            EmailMsgBody = "-- TOTAL # OF CONTRACTS WITH FAILSAFE DATE ON " + DateStr + " IS: " + icnt.ToString + vbCrLf +
            vbNewLine + "                                                                                                                                                 __________________                                                                                     " +
            vbNewLine +
            vbNewLine + "                                                                                                                                                 *****Contracts****                                                                                     " +
            vbNewLine + "                                                                                                                                                 __________________                                                                                     " +
            vbNewLine +
            vbNewLine + "Contract#" + "             " + "Vender Name" + "                                  " + "Termination Date" + "     " + "Dept Name" + "                                " + "Renewal Option" + "                      " + "Contract Desc" + "                                  " + "Email Address" +
            vbNewLine + "------------" + "             " + "-----------------" + "                                  " + "---------------------" + "     " + "--------------" + "                                " + "--------------------" + "                      " + "-----------------" + "                                  " + "-----------------" +
            vbNewLine + ContractNo.PadRight(18) + "  " + _
                VenderName.PadRight(38) + " " + _
                 TerminationDateStr.PadRight(26) + " " + _
                 DeptName.PadRight(27) + " " + _
                  RenewalOption.PadRight(45) + "   " + _
                 ContractDesc.PadRight(32) + "   " + _
                 ContactEmail.PadRight(11) + "  "
```

Comment: The end of your program is missing.

Comment: You are assigning a value to `EmailMsgBody` inside the `For Each` loop so each iteration will overwrite the previous text, leaving you with only the last value when the loop completes.  You need to either append in the loop or else add each value to a collection and then concatenate them all at the end.